# If $G \cong H \times K$, then $G/K \cong H$

Tags: abstract-algebra

This is a follow up to my previous question: [If $G \cong H/K$, does it follow that $H \cong G \times K$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541132/if-g-cong-h-k-does-it-follow-that-h-cong-g-times-k) which has been established as false, with fairly easy counter examples.

If I know that $G \cong H \times K$, then I know $G/K \cong H$, right? Here is my proof: let $\pi$ be the projection map from $G$ to $H$. Then $Ker(\pi) = K$, so $K$ is normal in $G$, and $G/K$ is a group. The result then follows from the first isomorphism theorem.

Is this correct? And I apologize if this is a duplicate, but it didn't come up in my searches (though it could easily be here with different notation)

Comment: While it is certainly true, your attempted proof lacks sufficient detail.  If the "projection map" is a homomorphism (some argument should be given at this level), then it has a kernel.  How do we know the kernel is *exactly* $K$?  It is fairly obvious that it contains $K$, but detail is important.

Comment: Rather than $G/K \cong H$ it should be $G/(\{1\} \times K) \cong H$.

Comment: When I write $G/K$, I write $K$ to mean the subgroup of $G$ isomorphic to $\{1\} \times K$.

Comment: Yes but there might be more subgroups isomorphic to $K$ in the direct product.